# Formatting the output of arrays, into a column

Tags: java, arrays, format

I just needed some assistance on formatting the output into a specific fashion. I satisfied all the requirements of the assignment, except the output.

I apologize for the bad format of this post, any suggestions and help is greatly appreciated.

I need the output to look like:

> Mr. Random - $500
>   Mr. BobRandom - $250
>   etc-8 more times
>   (sum total of all dollars)

Heres my code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class PeerTutors {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] myNameArray = new String[2];
        String[] myGradeArray = new String[2];
        double[] myStudentArray = new double[2];
        double[] stipend = new double[2];
        int sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            myNameArray[i] = (JOptionPane
                    .showInputDialog(null,
                            "Enter the Peer Tutor name, last name then followed by the first name."));

        }
        Arrays.sort(myNameArray, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Peer Tutors Names are :"
                + Arrays.toString(myNameArray));

        for (int a = 0; a < 2; a++) {
            myGradeArray[a] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                    "Please enter the highest degree earned for: "
                            + myNameArray[a]);
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Peer Tutors Names are :"
                + Arrays.toString(myNameArray) + Arrays.toString(myGradeArray));

        for (int b = 0; b < 2; b++) {
            myStudentArray[b] = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                    null, "Please enter the number of students"
                            + myNameArray[b] + " has assisted"));
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "The Peer Tutors Report: " + Arrays.toString(myNameArray)
                        + "with" + Arrays.toString(myStudentArray)
                        + " of children tutoring");

        for (int c = 0; c < 2; c++) {
            if (myGradeArray[c].equals("BS")) {
                stipend[c] = 9.5 * myStudentArray[c];

            } else if (myGradeArray[c].equals("MS")) {
                stipend[c] = 15 * myStudentArray[c];

            } else {
                stipend[c] = 20 * myStudentArray[c];
            }
        }
        for (double d : stipend) {
            sum += d;
        }

        for (int d = 0; d < 2; d++) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, myNameArray[d] + "-"
                    + stipend[d] + "\n");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post what your code is currently outputting?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, for each column, you need some kind of list (either an array or preferably an `List`).  You also need to maintain information on each columns max-width (I typically put this in another `List`).

You need to loop each line, breaking to down into it's column elements and place each element in the corresponding column `List`.  You should also be calculating the width requirements for each column as you go.

Once you have this all structured out, you need to then reconstruct the out put, using something like a `StringBuilder` to rebuild each line of the output but so that each column has the required additional spacing to allow the columns to flow.

**Updated with example**

Now, normally, I would store each row as an individual object, as it makes it easier to maintain a consistent idea of the total number of rows, but, using you code as a jumping off point...

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class TestTextColumnFormatting {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] myNameArray = new String[]{
            "Mr. Samete",
            "Ms. Torbura",
            "Mr. Perem",
            "Mr. Rothaw",
            "Miss. Endemos",
            "Mr. Chomoshon",
            "Mrs. Aldir",};
        double[] stipends = new double[]{
            500,
            200,
            300,
            1000,
            250,
            125,
            600,
            338
        };
        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        double tally = 0;

        int columnWidths[] = new int[2];
        for (int index = 0; index < myNameArray.length; index++) {
            columnWidths[0] = Math.max(columnWidths[0], myNameArray[index].length());
            columnWidths[1] = Math.max(columnWidths[1], nf.format(stipends[index]).length());
            tally += stipends[index];
        }

        columnWidths[1] = Math.max(columnWidths[1], nf.format(tally).length());

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(128);
        for (int index = 0; index < myNameArray.length; index++) {

            String name = myNameArray[index];
            String stipend = nf.format(stipends[index]);

            sb.append(name).append(fill(name, columnWidths[0], ' ')).append(" ");
            sb.append(fill(stipend, columnWidths[1], ' ')).append(stipend);
            sb.append("\n");

        }


        sb.append(fill("", columnWidths[0], ' ')).append(" ");
        sb.append(fill("", columnWidths[1], '=')).append("\n");
        sb.append(fill("", columnWidths[0], ' ')).append(" ");
        sb.append(fill(nf.format(tally), columnWidths[1], ' ')).append(nf.format(tally));
        sb.append("\n");

        System.out.println(sb.toString());

    }

    public static String fill(String sValue, int iMinLength, char with) {

        StringBuilder filled = new StringBuilder(iMinLength);

        while (filled.length() < iMinLength - sValue.length()) {

            filled.append(with);

        }

        return filled.toString();

    }
}
```

This will then output something like...

```
Mr. Samete      $500.00
Ms. Torbura     $200.00
Mr. Perem       $300.00
Mr. Rothaw    $1,000.00
Miss. Endemos   $250.00
Mr. Chomoshon   $125.00
Mrs. Aldir      $600.00
              =========
              $2,975.00
```

**Updated**

I'm such an idiot, I just realised that you're using a `JOptionPane` :P

The simplest solution would be to construct a HTML table and let Swing render it for you...

[image]

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class TestTextColumnFormatting {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] myNameArray = new String[]{
            "Mr. Samete",
            "Ms. Torbura",
            "Mr. Perem",
            "Mr. Rothaw",
            "Miss. Endemos",
            "Mr. Chomoshon",
            "Mrs. Aldir",};
        double[] stipends = new double[]{
            500,
            200,
            300,
            1000,
            250,
            125,
            600,
            338
        };
        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        double tally = 0;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(128);
        sb.append("<html><table border='0'>");
        for (int index = 0; index < myNameArray.length; index++) {

            String name = myNameArray[index];
            String stipend = nf.format(stipends[index]);

            sb.append("<tr><td align='left'>");
            sb.append(name);
            sb.append("</td><td align='right'>");
            sb.append(stipend);
            sb.append("</td></tr>");

            tally += stipends[index];

        }
        sb.append("<tr><td align='center'>");
        sb.append("</td><td align='right'>");
        sb.append(nf.format(tally));
        sb.append("</td></tr>");

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sb.toString());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1) Build a string from each of the lines. You can add two strings together by simply concatenating them with `+`, and to put them on separate lines concatenate them with a `System.lineSeparator()` in between which is a special string that will be whatever the newline ASCII is on your system. (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator%28%29 )

Solution 2) Add all the lines you want to be in the final string into an `ArrayList<String>`, then construct the output string by joining your list on `System.lineSeparator()` concatenation. Similar idea except the lines are logically separate until the very end.

If you need a specific width, I suggest you follow solution 2), except instead of making an ArrayList of the final result you want to print out, make ArrayLists of the components of each column, and note the largest entry in each column. Then, you can add spaces to all the other entries to make them just as large (for example, using a string formatter, the %s token and dynamically adding the width you need, on each entry: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html ). Then you can finally concatenate everything together and spit it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can append the given input to a `String` and then pass this to the `JOptionPane` as input. After getting names from the input just use a `String` and append all of the names to it for the display.

[image: Example Image]

```
  Arrays.sort(myNameArray);

  String nameString = new String();
  for(int i = 0; i < myNameArray.length; i++) {
      nameString = "\n" + nameString + myNameArray[i] + "\n";
  }

  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The Peer Tutors Names are :" + nameString);
```

Similarly you can do the same approach for other inputs also.