# How to print Strings in aligned columns in Java?

Tags: java, string, output, stringtokenizer

I hava a question on the printing Strings. The program should do the following job:
get a String as parameter and identify the words and prints them in three columns aligned:
Example:

```
the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
```

and output should be:

```
the  quick   brown
fox  jumped  over
the  lazy    dog
```

My solution was

```
private void printColumn(String s){
StringTokenizer toker = new StringTokenizer(s);
while (toker.hasMoreTokens()){
    String temp = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
  temp +=toker.nextToken();
}
    System.out.print(temp);
System.out.println();
}
}
```

but my output is not aligned

```
the  quick  brown
fox  jumped  over
the  lazy  dog
```

any advice please?

Comment: You need to know the maximum width of each column and pad enough spaces beyond it. Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15940485/formatting-the-output-of-arrays-into-a-column/15940611#15940611) (first half of the answer) demonstrates the basic idea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use printf(...) or String.format(...) and add the proper formatting.

**Do not** add a tab character "\t" after each word.
This solution is **bad** because if a word is longer than one tab space it would mess up (because it would tab to the next tab space after the word).

Thanks to Hovercraft Full Of Eels for the complete solution.