# Trouble with my Restaurant Billing program codes and calculating

Tags: java, checkbox, calculator

I need help regarding with the computation of what the user order it seems that the options doesn't have a value to be computed please help me how to put values in every options and one more thing is i need help with the codes for the checkbox for additional order I'm not really good in programming and this is all the effort i can do. I really need to pass this project right now so i need a quick answer and by the way what is the problem with my display to user?

Help with: Checkbox codes,Computation,JOptionPane Display

```
package project2;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Project2 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
List<String> optionList = new ArrayList<String>();
optionList.add("1");
optionList.add("2");
optionList.add("3");
optionList.add("4");


    double charge;
    double tax = 0.0675;
    double tipRate = 0.15;
    double totalWithTax;
    double taxAmount;
    double tipAmount;
    double grandTotal;

            //selection of food
            Object[] options = optionList.toArray();
            int value = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(
            null,
            "Please select your Burger:(1 or 2)\n 1. Burger                     $3.00 \n 2. Cheese Burger      $4.50 "
                    + "\n 2. Bacon Burger        $5.50 \n 2. Supreme Burger   $7.00",
            "Pick",
            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
            null,
            options,
            optionList.get(0));



    //calculate the charge and the tip
    taxAmount = charge * tax;
    totalWithTax = charge + taxAmount;
    tipAmount = totalWithTax * tipRate;
    grandTotal = totalWithTax + tipAmount;



            //Display it back to the user
            String opt = optionList.get(value);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You picked " + opt"  \n  meal: $" + charge" \n tax: $" + taxAmount" \n  meal + tax: $" + totalWithTax" \n  total cost(tip included): $" + grandTotal);




}
```

}

Comment: Your example won't compile...is that the problem your having...?

Answer (score 0):

Stepping over the compiler issues of the example.

You need some way to map the options to their prices, for example...

```
Map<String, Double> priceList = new HashMap<>(4);
priceList.put("1", 3d);
priceList.put("2", 4.5d);
priceList.put("3", 5.5d);
priceList.put("4", 7d);
```

Then, once the user has made there choice, you can get the price for the selected option using something like...

```
double price = priceList.get(optionList.get(value));
```

The problem with the display comes down to a number of issues.  Apart from the fact that it's possible that there might a variable width font in use, not all the columns are equal length.

A neat trick would be to use a `html` `table` as the display value, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15940485/formatting-the-output-of-arrays-into-a-column/15940611#15940611)

Comment: So you mean I gotta change optionList.add("1") into pricelist.put("1".3d); ?

Comment: No. Keep the `optionList`, this is what's used to be displayed on the screen, the `priceList` map simply provides you means to map a option to a price (so option "1" will be mapped to `3.0`, etc)...

Comment: Alright I got it my one last problem is the output. How should I display everything using JOptionPane?

Comment: See the linked [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15940485/formatting-the-output-of-arrays-into-a-column/15940611#15940611) for an example...

Comment: Please, please, do NOT use a `double` to store an amount of money.  MadProgrammer, you should know better than this!

Comment: @DavidWallace Given all the other crap that the OP is dealing with, that's the least of their worries and I'm pretty sure under/overflow of currency is not really a concern at this point in their learning.  But feel free to leave some links for when they are ready...

Comment: I would post my own answer to this, but I don't know what "I really need to pass this project right now so i need a quick answer and by the way what is the problem with my display to user?" actually means.  There doesn't seem to be any other question in the question.

Comment: @DavidWallace Why do you think I'm been vague on my answers. Try compiling the example and you might understand why I've avoid overly complicated response...

Comment: @DavidWallace What I mean by that is why i'm having errors with the output '//Display it back to the user' not to mention the +charge because I know the I haven't initialize it. But im already done with that problem. Since your willing to help why don't you help me with the checkbox thing. I want to make the program more better by adding checkbox on the burger selection for additional order like drinks and stuffs. To be specific it would be my first time putting a check box.

Comment: @user3457719 Then take a look at [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) and [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I used the codes in the link you just gave me and it was pretty helpful but there is one last thing i need to know regarding with the codes provided in the link you gave me. Since i already have `grandTotal = totalWithTax + tipAmount;` I won't be needing the codes to total everything.

Comment: @user3457719 The example was just that, an example, and idea, something to get you thinking.  You need apply the concept to your current problem