# How do I format a string in JOptionPane

Tags: java, string, string-formatting, currency

I found and fixed my error, i was formatting twice.

I am trying to display a dollar amount using JOptionPane, but since it is a double, I am getting extra digits after the decimal. How do I format while within JOptionPane? I tried using String.format but I am getting an error when I run it;

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException:
>   Format specifier '%.2f'
>
> ```
>  at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
>  at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
>  at java.lang.String.format(Unknown Source)
>  at CouponCalc.main(CouponCalc.java:38)
> ```

Here is my code;

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class CouponCalc {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double groceriesCost, discount;
        double tier1=.08, tier2=.1, tier3=.12, tier4=.14; //coupon percentages for easy adjustment

        groceriesCost = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter cost of groceries."));

        if (groceriesCost<0)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Entry"); //TODO implement loop
                System.exit(0);
            }

        else if (groceriesCost>=0 && groceriesCost<=9.99)   //No coupon
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You do not qualify for any coupons.)");


        else if (groceriesCost>=10.00 && groceriesCost<=59.99) //tier 1 coupon  
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, String.format("You win a discount coupon of $" + String.format("%.2f", (groceriesCost*tier1)) +
                                                ". (8% of your purchase.)"));
        else if (groceriesCost>=60.00 && groceriesCost<=149.99) //tier 2 coupon
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, String.format("You win a discount coupon of $" + String.format("%.2f", (groceriesCost*tier2)) +
                                                ". (10% of your purchase.)"));
        else if (groceriesCost>=150.00 && groceriesCost<=209.99) //tier 3 coupon
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, String.format("You win a discount coupon of $" + String.format("%.2f", (groceriesCost*tier3)) +
                                                ". (12% of your purchase.)"));
        else if (groceriesCost>=210.00) //tier 4 coupon
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, String.format("You win a discount of $" + String.format("%.2f", (groceriesCost*tier4)) +
                                                ". (14% of your purchase.)"));

        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(...

Comment: Since you'd do this the exact same way in AWT, a servlet or a command line app., it really has nothing to do with Swing. `System.exit(0);` ..and that is redundant at that point, since exiting the JRE is exactly what would have happened anyway.

Comment: “I am getting an error when I run it.”  Edit your question to include the *entire stack trace* of that error.

Comment: Given the nature of Fonts, it might be better to wrap the about in a html table, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15940485/formatting-the-output-of-arrays-into-a-column/15940611#15940611)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not format the whole string. Only the double.

```
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You win a discount coupon of $" + String.format("%.2f", (groceriesCost*tier1)) +
                                            ". (8% of your purchase.)");
```